# Error when I debug my Windows Store app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, unity-game-engine, windows-8.1, windows-store

When I build my Unity3D game on Visual Studio 2013, the error list has this error:

> Error    1   The command "echo UnityInstallationDir 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Unity\Editor' echo UnityProjectDir 'C:\Users\Ion
>   Aivatidis\Documents\Floppy Helicopter 2' echo Copying assemblies...
>   copy /Y "C:\Users\Ionas\Desktop\Floppy Helicopter 2\Floppy Helicopter
>   2\Unprocessed*" "C:\Users\Ionas\Desktop\Floppy Helicopter 2\Floppy
>   Helicopter 2\" echo Running AssemblyConverter... "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\metrosupport\Tools\AssemblyConverter.exe"
>   -platform=wsa81 "C:\Users\Ionas\Desktop\Floppy Helicopter 2\Floppy Helicopter 2\Assembly-UnityScript.dll" "C:\Users\Ionas\Desktop\Floppy
>   Helicopter 2\Floppy Helicopter 2\Boo.Lang.dll"
>   "C:\Users\Ionas\Desktop\Floppy Helicopter 2\Floppy Helicopter
>   2\UnityEngine.dll" "C:\Users\Ionas\Desktop\Floppy Helicopter 2\Floppy
>   Helicopter 2\UnityEngine.UI.dll" "C:\Users\Ionas\Desktop\Floppy
>   Helicopter 2\Floppy Helicopter 2\WinRTLegacy.dll" echo
>   AssemblyConverter done. " exited with code 3. Floppy Helicopter 2

(The Build Type is XAML C# Solution) (The SDK is Windows 8.1) (Development Build) 
(My Game is Unity3D game but I have build it for Windows 8.1 (Windows Store App) to publish it to Windows Store)

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Try to build in Unity rather then Visual Studio. Go to File->Build Settings You need to set the SDK to 'Phone 8.1' and run Windows 8 or higher.

[image: Unity build for Windows Store]

Comment: I Want to build it for Windows 8.1

Comment: And i have build it but when i go to visual studio and then when i debug it i have this error

Comment: @ionas9 Visual Studio isn't for debugging your unity applications, you need to use the unity editor for that. As far as I am aware my solution builds an app for Windows 8.1 using the Phone SDK.

Comment: i have build my game on unity but i want to create a windows store package (That means i have to build it to Visual Studio)

Comment: i need windows store package to upload it to windows dev portal

Comment: Take a look at the unity documentation on how to deploy a windows store app: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/windowsstore-deployment.html

Comment: i have generate visual studio solution

Comment: i have load this solution and then i have go to store>create app packages and when the app building the debbuger has this error